# How to access attached file from workflow transition screen in jira (groovy)

Tags: groovy, workflow, jira, transition

In a workflow transition I have a screen with an "attach file" input. In the post-function I want to access the attached file (if any) and create another issue with this file as attachment.

I tried to achieve this via the ServletActionContext.getRequest() but I can't seem to get the uploaded file this way. The HttpServletRequest does not have the getPart() function.

Is there an official way to access attached files from post-functions?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/98885/how-to-access-attached-file-from-workflow-transition-screen-in-jira-with-groovy%20) answer from Naykipap I found a working solution. Here's what I came up with:

```
// copy attachments uploaded in screen to new issue
def changeItems = transientVars["changeItems"]
def uploadChanges = changeItems.findAll { item -> item.getField() == "Attachment" && item.getFieldType() == "jira" }

uploadChanges.each { uploadChange ->
  def Attachment attachment = attachmentManager.getAttachment(uploadChange.getTo()?.toLong())
  if (attachment) {
    def filePath = PathUtils.joinPaths(pathManager.attachmentPath, currentIssue.projectObject.key, currentIssue.key, attachment.id.toString())
    def atFile = new File(filePath)
    if (atFile.canRead()) {
        log.debug("Cloning attachment ${attachment.filename}")
        attachmentManager.createAttachmentCopySourceFile(atFile, attachment.filename, attachment.mimetype, attachment.author, newIssue, [:], attachment.created)
    }
  }
}
```

**Important:** the script has to be executed after the issue is saved to db. Else there is no changeItems in the transientVars and/or the attachment is not saved to disk. I moved it right down to the end of executions and it worked fine for me.